# Checking values in a class list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically, I have a class for the Player of a game

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,inventory,hp):
        self.inventory = []
        self.hp = 20
    ...
    ...

P = Player()
```

And I simply want to check for an item in the inventory (where items are each a class as well)

```
class Book():
    def __init__(self,name,description):
        ...
        ...
```

Then do this.

```
if Book() in P.inventory:
    print("You have a book.")
else:
    print("You don't have a book.")
```

The problem I'm having is that even if the `Book()` object is in the player's inventory, it reads the `if` statement as false and runs the `else` statement.

I'm thinking I could try to use a `for` loop like so

```
for i in P.inventory:
    counter = 0
    if i == Book():
        print("You have a book.")
        counter = 1
if counter == 0:
    print("You don't have a book.")
```

but I'm hoping I won't have to use that much code for such a simple task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Book()` creates a new object everytime so `Book() == Book()` returns `False`. You might want to use `isinstance` instead:

```
a_book = Book()
isinstance(a_book, Book)
```

with something like:

```
def check_for_books(inventory):
    for i in inventory:
        if isinstance(i, Book):
            print("You have a book.")
            return
    else:
        print("You have no books.")
```

Comment: I see. The way I'm doing this, I'm not actually using any instances (I don't know if that's a good way to do it, but it's been easier for specifically what I need), so each item, room, and enemy is actually just a subclass of the classes Item, Room, and Enemy.  I can see that this problem just stems from my ignorance regarding the nature of classes. I'll try to work on a solution, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, what you're trying to accomplish is something that will become loads easier once you think about everything in terms of instances.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if just care about the book, treating the books with the same name and same description as an identity book. You'd better overwrite the eq and hash method of the book.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, inventory=None, hp=None):
        if inventory is None:
            inventory = []
        self.inventory = inventory
        self.hp = hp


class Book:
    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other and self.name == other.name and self.description == other.description

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.name, self.description))


player = Player([Book('Harry Potter', 'Volume I'), Book('Harry Potter', 'Volume II')], 20)

print(Book('Harry Potter', 'Volume I') in player.inventory) # True
print(Book('Harry Potter', 'Volume V') in player.inventory) # False
```

So you don't have to worry about if the book you wanna check is exactly the instance in memory. Due to in most cases, your data should be stored in db, not in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
>>> class Book():
...     def __init__(self,name,description):
...         self.name = name
...         self.description = description
... 
>>> class Player:
...     def __init__(self,inventory,hp):
...         self.inventory = inventory
...         self.hp = hp
... 
>>> b = Book('myname', 'mydesc')
>>> p = Player([b], 'hp')
>>> b in p.inventory
True
```

This returns False because it is a different instance of Book:

```
>>> c = Book('myname', 'mydesc')
>>> c in p.inventory
False
```

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. The only problem is that, for reasons, I'm not using instances of any classes, I'm only using the classes themselves, but I think now that I know what my problem is, I can figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check the object type of the items in the inventory to see if they are of class `Book()`

```
for o in P.inventory:
    if isinstance(o, Book()):
        print("You have a book.")
        break
else:
    print("You don't have a book.")
```

Notice that the `else` statement is part of the `for` statement, not the `if` statement